# How to z-index an element higher than it's containing element

Tags: css, z-index, galleria, zurb-foundation

I'm using a combination of [Zurb's Off Canvas Layout](http://www.zurb.com/playground/off-canvas-layouts) and [Galleria](http://galleria.io/) on a page.

Zurb's layout is used for the general structure and Galleria creates a photo viewer that can be switched to full-screen.

The HTML is basically like this (simplified):

```
<section role="complementary" style="z-index: 2;"> Sidebar Content </section>
<section role="main" style="z-index: 1;">
    <div id="galleria"> [small images here, no problem with these]
        <div class="fullscreen" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 999;">
            [fullscreen images go here, the sidebar appears above them]
        </div>
    </div>
 </section>
```

Since the full-screen images  container (z-index: 999) is contained in a lower z-index main  than the complementary , when viewing the images in full-screen mode, the complementary sidebar  appears above the images.

I would much rather not change these technologies I'm using and hoping someone has a CSS solution to this problem.

I already saw a [discouraging post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7564354/how-to-make-zindex-of-a-ui-element-relative-to-the-parent-canvas-and-not-the-con), but maybe someone knows something they don't?

Comment: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/15/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/

Answer (score 0):

You have to position the element. Use `position:absolute`, `position:relative`, or `position:fixed` for your element with the class `.fullscreen`